# Gson custom deserializer for String class

Tags: java, json, gson, json-deserialization

I am using GSON to convert a json to a POJO but values of the keys in json may contain whitespaces and I wanted to trim them. For that I wrote a custom String deserializer but that isn't working. Here is want I have:

```
public class Foo {
  public int intValue;
  public String stringValue;

  @Override
  public String toString() {
      return "**" + stringValue + "**" ;
  }
}

public void testgson()
{
    String json = "{\"intValue\":1,\"stringValue\":\" one two  \"}";
    GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
    gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(String.class, new StringDeserializer());
    Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();
    Foo a = gson.fromJson(json, Foo.class);
    System.out.println(a.toString()); //prints ** one two ** instead of **one two**

}

class StringDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<String>
{
    @Override public String deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context)
        throws JsonParseException
    {
        String a = json.toString().trim();
        System.out.print(a); //prints ** one two **
        return a;
    }
}
```

I expected the output to be `**one two**` but that isn't the case. What am I doing wrong

Comment: `trim()` only takes whitespace off the beginning and end of a string, not out of the middle.

Comment: @azurefrog I want to remove beginning and ending whitespaces only.

Comment: There is no beginning and end whitespace before or after `**`... How about `return "**" + stringValue.trim() + "**" ;`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `StringDeserializer`, this

```
json.toString()
```

is calling `toString` on a `JsonElement` that is specifically a `JsonPrimitive` containing a value that is text. [Its `toString` implementation](https://static.javadoc.io/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.8.5/com/google/gson/JsonElement.html#toString--) returns the JSON representation of its content, which is, literally, the String `" one two  "`. `trim` doesn't do what you want it because that String is enclosed in `"`.

What you really wanted to do was read the content of the JSON element. You can do that with one of `JsonElement`'s convenience method: `getAsString()`.

So

```
String a = json.getAsString().trim();
```

would then print what you expected.